# Expose Enum values as @Beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an architecture where an Enum is implementing an interface.

```
public interface Animal {
  String getLatinName();
}
```

And then an enum with some subtypes

```
@Component //Something like this is what I am after
public enum Feline implements Animal {
   CAT("Felis Catus"),
   LYNX("Lynx Lynx");    
}
```

This allows dependant libraries to extend the instances, but for this I would need a mechanism like the following, so I can collect them all by means of the ComponentScan

```
@Autowire
Set<Animal> animals;  //Injecting all occurrences of Animal instances
```

For this approach, I need to make all instances of my enum Feline to be scannable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `@Bean` methods, but you'd have to create a method for each enum value.

```
@Configuration
public class FelineConfig {

    @Bean
    public Feline cat() {
        return Feline.CAT;
    }

    @Bean
    public Feline lynx() {
        return Feline.LYNX;
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want all the enum values auto-registered, you can do it with a [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html):

```
@Configuration
public class FelineConfig implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        for (Feline feline : Feline.values()) {
            String beanName = Feline.class.getName() + "." + feline.name();
            beanFactory.registerSingleton(beanName, feline);
        }
    }

}
```